# Adding function to last element in mapped object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, dictionary

I have a problem with adding function to last element of my mapped object.

It's React.

I have a function "handleToggle" - after click, there should be seen elements from last div. Each element, after click has blue frame - only one at a time. So after click the last element ('bottom')there shoud be frame too and under this I want to display some other options from div which is at the end of my code. Please, help me - I don't know how to add function to last element of a map.

````
export default function EditorColor(props) {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);
  const handleToggle = () => setIsShown(!isShown);

  const [isChosen, setChosenIcon] = useState('');

  const contourIcons = [
    { id: 1, type: 'square' },
    { id: 2, type: 'rounded' },
    { id: 3, type: 'circle' },
    { id: 4, type: 'bottom' },
  ];

  const handleChosenIcon = e => {
    setChosenIcon(e.target.title);
    console.log(e.target.title);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {contourIcons.map(icon => (
          <div
            key={icon.id}
            title={icon.type}
            className={`contour ${isChosen === icon.type ? 'active-tab' : ''}`}
            onClick={handleChosenIcon}
          >
            {props.name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      {isShown && (
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Comment: Sounds like you'll want to add `setIsShown(e.target.title == 'bottom');` to your `handleChosenIcon` function?

Comment: thank you so much, it's working! :)

Answer (score 0):

according to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `array.map` has an optional parameter named index so you can use it to know that the index of the element is returning now

```
{
contourIcons.map((icon, index) => {
  if(index === contourIcons.length - 1) {
    //return what you want
  }
  return (
    <div
      key={icon.id}
      title={icon.type}
      className={`contour ${isChosen === icon.type ? 'active-tab' : ''}`}
      onClick={handleChosenIcon}
    >
        {props.name}
    </div>
  )})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want, but what I did is passing a check if the last element is clicked:

```
           handleChosenIcon(icon.type, index === contourIcons.length - 1);
```

If the check is passed, handleToggle will be called.
If it is not exactly what you want, you can still base on the sample to change the code to suit your needs:
https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-flower-2bs96?file=/src/App.js:152-164